# Conditional assignment in a loop

Tags: pstricks, conditionals, programming, loops, foreach

### Objective:

I want to compile the `temporary.tex` file containing PSTricks code twice. One with `-jobname=Rotated` and the other one with `-jobname=Unrotated`. The resulting `Rotated.ps` will be passed to `ps2pdf` without `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` but the `Unrotated.ps` will be passed to `ps2pdf` with  `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`.

The following code throws some errors. The error messages can be seen by yourself.

```
% this input file name is filename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
    \rput{90}(2,1){Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

\newif\ifAutoRotatePages

\def\AutoRotatePages{%
    \ifAutoRotatePages
        % do nothing
    \else
        -dAutoRotatePages=/None
    \fi}

\def\JobName#1{-jobname=#1}

\foreach \outputname/\isautorotate in {Rotated/true,Unrotated/false}
{
    \AutoRotatePages\isautorotate
    \foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex \JobName{\outputname}/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf \AutoRotatePages/ps}
    {
        \immediate\write18{\compiler\space \outputname.\ext}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \filename in {Rotated,Unrotated}{\begin{center}\includegraphics{\filename}\end{center}}
\end{document}
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 \AutoRotatePages\isautorotate
```

will pass a macro with value `true` or `false` to `\AutoRotatePages` so you could redefine your macro to accept such a string but simpler is just to do

```
 \csname AutoRotatePages\isautorotate\endcsname
```

together with

```
\def\AutoRotatePagestrue{}


\def\AutoRotatePagesfalse{ -dAutoRotatePages=/None }
```

No need for a new if